# Why must an electric field be radial due to symmetry?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, symmetry, gauss-law

I'm learning about Gauss's law and was reading Electricity and Magnetism by Purcell and Introduction to Electrodynamics by Griffiths where it said that due to spherical, cylindrical, or planar symmetry, the electric field vector always is in the radial direction with direction in the $r$ vector - because it is the only unique direction. Can anyone explain this in further detail?

Comment: What case are you asking about - a point charge?

Comment: If a charge density has, say, spherical symmetric then so too does the potential have that same symmetry. E.g., $\rho(\vec r)=\rho(\vec r)\to\phi(\vec r)=\phi(r)$. Since the field is the gradient of the potential, the field points in the radial direction (the gradient of a function points in the direction of maximum change).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the work done in bringing unit positive charge from infinity to a distance $r$ from the point charge.

Irrespective of the path taken the work done to arrive anywhere at a distance $r$ from the charge is the same.

Thus the spherical surface of radius $r$ centred on the charge is an equipotential.

Moving a test charge along this equipotential  surface requires no work to be done, thus any force on the test charge is at right angles to the equipotential surface and that force is in the direction of an electric field line, ie radial.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the electric field from a static point charge, you can use a coordinate system with the charge/source at the origin. Since the charge is a single static "point", it has spherical symmetry (no matter how you rotate the system, the system is unchanged).

Integrating Gauss' law $\nabla \cdotp E = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$ over the volume of a sphere (and using spherical coordinates, due to the symmetry), we find that the electric field only has a component along $\hat{r}$. (Can be seen from the divergence theorem. I'm certain Griffiths does this.) You can define the charge density $\rho$ using the Dirac delta function.

I am not sure what you mean with "unique direction", sorry. This is my first post so I assume someone else can explain better!

Comment: What about a group of point, static charges

Comment: @EmilSriram No, a group of two or more (but a finite number) point charges will not produce a spherically symmetric field. The charge distribution of a group of two or more point charges generally does not have spherical symmetry about any point, which leads to the electrostatic potential also not having that symmetry, which means the field doesn't have to be radial.

Answer (score 1):

> Why must an electric field be radial due to symmetry?

There is no general requirement for an electric field to be radial.

A static electric field is radial when the symmetric of the charge density (the source of the field) has radial symmetry. This follows from the relationship between the charge density and the potential (in Gaussian units):
$$
-\nabla^2\phi(\vec r) = 4\pi\rho(\vec r)\;,
$$
which can be inverted to find the particular solution:
$$
\phi(\vec r) =\int d^3r' \rho(\vec r')\frac{1}{|\vec r - \vec r'|}\;.
$$

To consider the effect of, say, spherical symmetry, you can expand $\frac{1}{|\vec r - \vec r'|}$ in the basis of spherical harmonics ("Laplace expansion") to find:
$$
\phi(\vec r) =\sum_{\ell, m}\frac{4\pi(-1)^m}{2\ell + 1}Y_{\ell,m}(\hat r)\int d^3r' \frac{r_<^\ell}{r_>^{\ell+1}}Y_{\ell,-m}(\hat r')\rho(\vec r')\;.\tag{1}
$$

If, say, the charge density $\rho$ is spherically symmetric then:
$$
\rho(\vec r) = \rho_0(r)Y_{0,0}(\hat r)=\rho_0(r)\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}
$$
from which Eq. (1) becomes:
$$
\phi(\vec r) =\sum_{\ell, m}\frac{4\pi(-1)^m}{2\ell + 1}Y_{\ell,m}(\hat r)\int dr' r'^2 \frac{1}{r_>^{1}}\delta_{\ell,0}\delta_{m,0}\rho_0( r')\;.\tag{2}
$$
$$
=\sqrt{4\pi}\int dr' r'^2 \frac{1}{r_>^{1}}\rho_0( r')\;.\tag{3}
$$
In the further special case where $r>r'$, we find (surprise, surprise):
$$
\phi(\vec r) = \frac{Q_{tot}}{r}
$$
Or, in SI units:
$$
\phi(\vec r) = \frac{Q_{tot}}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r}
$$
Or, in terms of the field:
$$
\vec E(\vec r) = \frac{Q_{tot}}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r^3}\vec r\;.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you are standing in front of the charge and the electric field not only has a radial but also has a tangential field.Now suppose you close your eyes and someone rotates the charge distribution by some certain angle about a diameter which points towards you.Now the radial component will be the same and directed towards you but the tangential component will also have rotates by that certain angle.Now suppose you open your eyes.If the charge distribution has spherical symmetry then the charge distribution would look exactly the same to you as before but now the field will be in a different direction(because the tangential component is rotated by some angle).The same charge distribution cannot produce different electric field,so the tangential component of the field must be zero.